# How to read scatter plot points draw towards y-axis vertically in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm using iris dataset of sklearn module and I just simply split this data into train and test like this

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x_input,y_target, test_size=0.2)
```

and then using liner-model fit the data:

```
lr= LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

output

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False)
```

then ure predict

```
y_hat=lr.predict(x_train)
```

And then I simply plot data y_train,y_hat using this code:

```
plt.scatter(y_train,y_hat,c="orange")
plt.xlabel('Target (y_train)',size=18)
plt.ylabel('Prediction (y_hat)',size=18)
```

OutPut:(But I don't know what is the meaning of this plotted data..)

[image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? are you wanting to plot the error of your model?

Comment: I'm learning ML and it's concepts like overfitting etc..that's why i'm try ploting different thing..and i actually even don't know the meaning of above picture